Ive made a batch file wait, but i have no idea how to make the countdown hidden in the cmd. can anyone tell me how i can hide the countdown?
I made a batch file that counts down, but I forgot how to hide it, and I can't find a clear answer on google. :( can anyone tell me how I can hide the countdown? also I used the command timeout /t 4 /no break, which works fine, but I don't know how to hide the countdown.
I tried typing hide after it, resulted in nothing.

%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /t 4 /nobreak 1>NUL

Does this answer your question? How to hide batch output

after timeout /t 4 /no break add >nul.
and the space between /no break can be removed
